# No encuentra mis rutas en producción en Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, rutas

Estoy desarrollando una *app web* en *Laravel*, ya la tengo terminda y quiero subirla a mi propio servidor que es un *Linux Server* en *Ubuntu*, y cuando entro al enlace `http://192.168.11.79/gps/public/`, me da *error 404*.

¿Tengo que modificar algún archivo en *Laravel*?

Comment: Bienvenido por favor lee [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente debes modificar el archivo index.php que se encuentra en public/ Debes poner mucha atención a estas lineas ya que debe coincidir con tu carpeta vendor.

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

Debes jugar con las rutas absolutas y relativas.

Comment: Soy nuevo en laravel como podria saber , cual es la ruta correcta?